# Is the Keccak family of sponge constructions the same as SHA-3?

Tags: hash, nist, keccak, sponge

I can't seem to come across a clear and to the point answer. Is SHA-3 in the same situation as ElGamal and DSA, where it is modified slightly, or is the original Keccak submission the exact same as NIST standardized SHA-3?

Comment: Related: [What are the key differences between the draft SHA-3 standard and the Keccak submission?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15727/what-are-the-key-differences-between-the-draft-sha-3-standard-and-the-keccak-sub) as well as [Are NIST's changes to Keccak/SHA-3 problematic?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10645/are-nists-changes-to-keccak-sha-3-problematic?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

SHA-3 is defined by [FIPS 202](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf).

If you go to the [team Keccak](https://keccak.team) website you will read the following.

> Keccak is a versatile cryptographic function. Best known as a hash function, it nevertheless can also be used for authentication, (authenticated) encryption and pseudo-random number generation. Its structure is the extremely simple sponge construction and internally it uses the innovative Keccak-f cryptographic permutation.
>
> **After its selection as the winner of the SHA-3 competition**, **Keccak has been standardized** in 3GPP TS 35.231 for mobile telephony (TUAK), and **in NIST standards FIPS 202 and SP 800-185**. Consequently, it has received extensive public scrutiny and third-party cryptanalysis.
> [[source]](https://keccak.team/keccak.html)

Thus **Keccak[1600] is the exact same as NIST standardized in SHA-3**.

Comment: Does Keccak have that strange empty string that gets attached also?

Comment: I don't understand your question.